# Reading RFID Tag once (with RFID RC522 Chip) stops thread

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, rfid, raspberry-pi4

I'm running some code on my PI 4B which requires multiple threads. I'm using events to manage the threads and stop them whenever there is a keyboard interrupt or whenever the function that runs when mainBUtton is pressed.

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import time
import os


def setup():

    GPIO.setwarnings(False)

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)     

    GPIO.setup(relayPin, GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.setup(ledPinRed, GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.setup(ledPinGreen, GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.setup(buzzerPin, GPIO.OUT)

    

    global Buzz 

    Buzz = GPIO.PWM(buzzerPin, 440) 

    GPIO.setup(mainButtonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)    # set buttonPin to PULL UP INPUT mode

    GPIO.setup(faceRecPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)    # set buttonPin to PULL UP INPUT mode

    discordPing.getTokenID("token.txt")



def action():

    GPIO.output(ledPinRed,GPIO.LOW)

    GPIO.output(ledPinGreen, GPIO.HIGH)

    GPIO.output(relayPin, GPIO.HIGH)

    time.sleep(5)

    GPIO.output(ledPinGreen, GPIO.LOW)

    GPIO.output(relayPin, GPIO.LOW)







def destroy(): 

    GPIO.output(relayPin, GPIO.LOW)

    GPIO.cleanup()



def onPress():

    GPIO.output(relayPin, GPIO.LOW)

    buzzerThread = Thread(target=buzzerLoop)

    buzzerThread.start()

    buzzerThread.join()   

    

def buzzerLoop():

    print("Starting Buzzer")

    Buzz.start(50)

    ringEvent = Event()

    ledThread = Thread(target=ledLoop,args=(ringEvent,))

    rfidThread = Thread(target=rfidReader, args=(ringEvent,))

    rfidThread.start()

    ledThread.start()

    for i in range(1, len(song)):

        Buzz.ChangeFrequency(song[i])

        time.sleep(beat[i]*0.13)

    Buzz.stop()

    ringEvent.set()

    ledThread.join()

    #rfidThread.join()





def ledLoop(ringEvent):

    print("Starting LED")

    while True:

        if ringEvent.is_set():

            break

        else:

            GPIO.output(ledPinRed, GPIO.LOW)

            time.sleep(.75)

            GPIO.output(ledPinRed, GPIO.HIGH)

            time.sleep(.75)

    

def loop(event):

    while True:

        if event.is_set():

            print("Button Functionality Shutting Down")

            break

        else:

            if GPIO.input(mainButtonPin)==GPIO.LOW:

                print("Main BUtton Pressed")    

                onPress()

            elif GPIO.input(faceRecPin)==GPIO.LOW:

                print("starting face-rec")

                fullFaceRecognition(event)

            else : 

                pass

                #GPIO.output(ledPinRed,GPIO.HIGH)
def openFile(filename):

    with open(filename, "r") as file:

        lines = len(file.readlines())

        file.seek(0)

        for x in range(lines):

            code = (file.readline()).strip('\n')

            listOfCodes.append(code)

def rfidReader(event):

    reader = SimpleMFRC522()   

    code = ''

    count = 0

    while True:

        if event.is_set():

            print("RFID Shutting Down")

            break

        print(f"Starting RFID - ID#{count}")

        code = reader.read_id()

        print(f"Read {count}")

        count += 1

        if code != '':

            read = False

            for x in listOfCodes:

                if x == str(code):

                    print("Valid Code - Unlocking")

                    '''action()'''

                    code = ''

                    read = True

                    #time.sleep(3)

                    break

                else:

                    pass

            if read == False:

                code = ''

                print("Invalid User")

relayPin = 36

ledPinRed = 11

ledPinGreen = 13

mainButtonPin = 31

faceRecPin = 32

buzzerPin = 37 

mainEvent = Event()

#Main Code

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        setup()

        mainLoopThread = Thread(target=loop, args=(mainEvent,))

        mainLoopThread.start()

        mainLoopThread.join()


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program Ended")
        mainEvent.set()
        destroy()
```

Although this may be obvious though I think it's still important, the main button aswell as the RFID Tag needs to be used more than once so The objective is to not have the mainLoop stop after one RFID Tag Read but rather have the ability to keep looping the if statement.

Output of code

```
Main BUtton Pressed
Starting Buzzer
Starting LED
Starting RFID - ID#0
Read 0
Valid Code - Unlocking
RFID Shutting Down
Button Functionality Shutting Down
```

After this the button doesn't work due to the loop being broken.